# converting contents of a "string array" AKA SAFEARRAY to wchar

Tags: c, windows, wmi

I'm using WMI to read DefaultIPGateway on the WMI object Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(VS.85).aspx) says it's a "String Array" and visual studio interprets this as a SAFEARRAY on the VARIANT object returned when you query the WMI.

How do you access the information inside the array? How do you convert each element to a wchar* or char*?

Code is appreciated

ps: note that i don't know anything about COM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SafeArrayAccessData to access the array elements.  There is a sample snippet in the MSDN Library article for it that also works with strings.  The elements should be BSTR, just wcscpy() into a wchar_t[].